Can a variable be passed to the same program to iterate over, instead of editing the source and running it with distinct values?
My MWE is:
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,dvipsnames,svgnames,dvipsnames,hyperref}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border={2pt},tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, line width=1pt]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);% centre of circle
\tikzmath{%
\radius = 1;% common radius of  circle and inscribed polygon; can be changed
\sides = 6;% number of sides of regular polygon
\Radius = \radius/cos (180/\sides);% radius of circumscribed polygon
}
\foreach \i in {1,...,\sides}{
  \coordinate (C\i) at (360/\sides*\i:\radius);% polar coordinates (theta:r)
}
\draw [color=BrickRed] (C1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\sides} {-- (C\i)} -- cycle;% inscribed polygon
\foreach \i in {1,...,\sides}{
  \coordinate (D\i) at (360/\sides*\i:\Radius);% polar coordinates (theta:r)
}
\draw [color=SlateGray] (D1) \foreach \i in {2,...,\sides} {-- (D\i)} -- cycle;% circumscribed polygon
\draw [color=OliveGreen] (O) circle (\radius);% common circle
\node [color=SteelBlue] at (O) {$n = \sides$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I want to run this code with different values of the variable \sides.
One way is to modify the value assigned to sides by editing the file and re-running it each time.
But is there a more elegant way of passing the program a list or array and allowing it to iterate and produce the different results in a single run?
This is a use case I have not faced before in LaTeX,  although it would be trivial with argc and argv in C. Hence my query.

Do you want a single PDF with the different results or one PDF per setting of your \sides variable.  Both are possible.

I want a separate PDF for each value of \sides.

Then replace \sides=6 in your code by \sides=\MySides and lauch compilation pdflatex \\def\\MySides{12} \\input foo.tex if your file is called foo.tex.  I am using here shell syntax for typical Unix, it will be perhaps different on Windows.

Notice that one can construct a master TeX file you can compile with shellescape and that will automatize my previous comment to loop over some list of sides values, but I would rather use some shell script.
